# How to SetUp Object Repository in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, frameworks, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to setup an Object Repository in Selenium Webdriver in order to make sure that future changes in objects don't impact my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view [PageObjects](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) are the way to go.

That simple!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a CSV with all the object locator's....
2. A CSV parser and store all the values in a multidimensional array with column and and row as index..
3. Use that array wherever you need to use the locater in the code...
4. If you don't want to have the hard-coded index values for the array then you will need to have some increment mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

```
  try{
    while(loc_index<=loc_type.size()-1){
    //  System.out.println("1sy");
    while(loc_val_index<=loc_val.size()){
        while(obj_index<=obj_value.size()-1){   
          String loc_data = loc_type.get(loc_index);
          if(loc_data.equals("name")){           
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(loc_val.get(loc_val_index)));
    if (element!=null){
        try {
       element.sendKeys(obj_value.get(obj_index)); } catch (Exception e){}
       obj_index++;}}else if(loc_data.equals("xpath")){
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(loc_val.get(loc_val_index)));
      if (element!=null){                            
          element.sendKeys(obj_value.get(obj_index));  
           Log("Data Entered");
          obj_index++;}}
      else if(loc_data.equals("id")){ 
      try{
          WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(loc_val.get(loc_val_index))); 
          if (element!=null){
             element.sendKeys(obj_value.get(obj_index));                                
               obj_index++;}} catch (Exception e) {}}
             break;}
        loc_val_index++;
        break;}
    loc_index++;
    }
        }catch (Exception e){}
        finally{
            obj_index=0;
            loc_index=0;
            loc_val_index=0;
        }
```